# Select Distinct by 4 columns and return all columns in table

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I need to return select distinct for first 4 column together,and return all others column remaining.For Example if i Have:

```
DEPTNO LOC           JOB              SAL ENAME
---------- ------------- --------- ---------- ----------
    10 NEW YORK      CLERK           1300 MILLER
    10 NEW YORK      MANAGER         2450 CLARK
    10 NEW YORK      CLERK           1300 KING
    20 DALLAS        ANALYST         3000 FORD
    20 DALLAS        ANALYST         3000 SCOTT
    20 DALLAS        CLERK            800 SMITH
    20 DALLAS        CLERK           1100 ADAMS
    20 DALLAS        MANAGER         2975 JONES
    30 CHICAGO       CLERK            950 JAMES
    30 CHICAGO       MANAGER         2850 BLAKE
    30 CHICAGO       SALESMAN        1250 MARTIN
    30 CHICAGO       SALESMAN        1250 WARD
    30 CHICAGO       SALESMAN        1500 TURNER
    30 CHICAGO       SALESMAN        1600 ALLEN
```

I need to return:

```
 DEPTNO LOC           JOB              SAL ENAME
---------- ------------- --------- ---------- ----------
    10 NEW YORK      CLERK           1300 MILLER
    10 NEW YORK      MANAGER         1300 CLARK
    20 DALLAS        ANALYST         3000 SCOTT
    20 DALLAS        CLERK            800 SMITH
    20 DALLAS        CLERK           1100 ADAMS
    20 DALLAS        MANAGER         2975 JONES
    30 CHICAGO       CLERK            950 JAMES
    30 CHICAGO       MANAGER         2850 BLAKE
    30 CHICAGO       SALESMAN        1250 MARTIN
    30 CHICAGO       SALESMAN        1500 TURNER
    30 CHICAGO       SALESMAN        1600 ALLEN
```

In other words if first 4 column are unique(togheter) i return  whole row.

I try with `select distinct` but i get only column that i write in command:

```
select distinct DEPTNO,LOC,JOB,SAL from my_table
```

will not return ENAME.

Than I try to use inner join, but than I get all columns from table.

Thanx

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified how you want it to choose between multiple ENAMEs. In this example, it returns the first one in alphabetical order:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       deptno
      ,loc
      ,job
      ,sal
      ,MIN(ename)
       OVER (PARTITION BY deptno, loc, job, sal)
       AS ename
FROM my_table;
```

Comment: Thanx for answer, `ename` is ok to not be unique, i can have more row with same `ename`.

Comment: Hi @Nick, sorry I'm not sure what you mean by that. Your question stipulated you only want one row for each deptno+loc+job+sal but did not state how the query should choose which ename to show on any particular row.

Answer (score 0):

you also can try this way

```
Example :

create table ttt
(   
    DEPTNO  int     ,
    LOC            varchar(20),
    JOB               varchar(20),
    SAL  int,
    ENAME varchar(20)
)
```

--

```
insert into 
ttt
values(10,'NEW YORK','CLERK',1300,'MILLER'),
(10,'NEW YORK','MANAGER',2450,'CLARK'),
(10,'NEW YORK','MANAGER',2450,'KING')
```

--

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT 
  DEPTNO,
  LOC,
  JOB,
  SAL,
  MAX(ENAME) from ttt
GROUP BY 
  DEPTNO,
  LOC,
  JOB,
  SAL
```

Here is the SQL Fiddle for this

[Click To See Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4fb1b/1)

Comment: @Nick I have created demo Please have a look at it